# How to open and close a device in Rust such as "/dev/something"?

Tags: linux, operating-system, rust

In C I can use the function `open` to open a file or anything else such as `/dev/something`. And there's `close` as well. How can I open and close `/dev/something` in Rust?

In fact, I also need to write to and read from it. How can I do that?

Comment: Please don't deface your post by rolling back our improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::fs::File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) should work for "/dev/something" as well.
You can use `File::open` for reading files.

Below is example for reading from `/dev/null`.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
let mut f = File::open("/dev/null")?;
let mut s = String::new();
try!(f.read_to_string(&mut s));
println!("s:'{}'", s);
```